# How to combine two Post/Category tables MYSQL SELECT queries into one

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL queries:

```
1) "SELECT ID,post_title,post_category,post_perma FROM ".TBL_POSTS."
   WHERE  published='1' AND page='0' ORDER BY  ID DESC LIMIT 10"

2) "SELECT p.cat_ID,p.cat_nicename FROM ".TBL_CATEGORIES." n, ".TBL_CATEGORIES." p
   WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt AND n.cat_ID='".post_category."' ORDER BY p.lft
```

First query selects posts and then second select the Path of the category by `post_category` please note that `post_category` will be taken from first query means `post_category` is common in both table.. in first table it is named as `post_category` and in second it is `cat_ID`

Right now I am running it in foreach loop which is not good. Also one thing to be noticed that second query will also return Array and that one array should correspond to `post_category`

Can any SQL expert help me?

Many Thanx

Comment: Will you please elaborate table structure?

Comment: I tried.. but not able to get the desired result.. can you please show me example?

Comment: please edit the question with what you have tried?

Comment: same query i tried as given by @Danny Hearnah .. i was getting just one last cat_nicename while i needed to have an array of path from second table

Answer (score 4):

Please try this it might be helpful to you.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.post_title,a.post_category,a.post_perma, b.cat_ID, b.cat_nickname
FROM  (SELECT ID,post_title,post_category,post_perma FROM ".TBL_POSTS." WHERE  published='1' AND page='0' ORDER BY  ID DESC LIMIT 10)  a
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT p.cat_ID as cat_ID,p.cat_nicename as cat_nickname FROM " . TBL_CATEGORIES . " n, " . TBL_CATEGORIES . " p WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt AND n.cat_ID = '" .$post_category. "' ORDER BY p.lft) b ON a.ID = b.cat_ID
```

Comment: Hi.. when i am changing $post_category as a.post_category  it says a.post_category is unknown column.. $post_category is not a variable.. it was being used when i was getting post_category from first query.. while here it should be linked with the TBL_POST only.. :(

Comment: Yes of course it is working.. I have post my question in much detail here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974224/combine-two-mysql-select-queries  please take a look buddy.. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use **[LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html)**

Like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `p`.`ID`,`p`.`post_title`,`p`.`post_category`,`p`.`post_perma`,`c`.`cat_ID`,`c`.`cat_nicename` FROM `".TBL_POSTS."` AS `p` ";
$sql .= "LEFT JOIN `".TBL_CATEGORIES."` AS `c` ON `c`.`cat_ID`=`p`.`post_category` WHERE `p`.`published`='1' AND `p`.`page`='0' ORDER BY `p`.`ID` DESC LIMIT 10";
```

You may need to tweak the `WHERE` clause to suite your needs more..

**Please Note:** This is one string, i have just split them onto two lines so it is easier to read. `.=` is to append the current string.

Comment: Hi.. thank you for the answer.. but there is an issue with your query.. In your select it is selecting just one last `cat_nicename` while in my second query.. i was getting cat_nicename in array.. so that i can make path of returned category ..getting me?

Comment: Ah yes i did not see that - sorry for that, have a look at @Suryawanshi Manoj 's answer