# Combine two MYSQL SELECT queries

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to combine two Post/Category tables MYSQL SELECT queries into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972130/how-to-combine-two-post-category-tables-mysql-select-queries-into-one)

I have two MYSQL queries:

```
1) "SELECT ID,post_title,post_category,post_perma FROM ".TBL_POSTS."
   WHERE  published='1' AND page='0' ORDER BY  ID ASC LIMIT 50"

2) "SELECT p.cat_ID,p.cat_nicename FROM ".TBL_CATEGORIES." n, 
   ".TBL_CATEGORIES." p
   WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft 
   AND p.rgt AND n.cat_ID='".post_category."' ORDER BY p.lft
```

I use it like this:

```
$sql="SELECT ID, post_title, post_category,post_perma 
      FROM ".TBL_POSTS." 
      WHERE  published='1' 
      AND page='0' 
      ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 50";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

$sql2="SELECT p.cat_ID, p.cat_nicename 
       FROM ".TBL_CATEGORIES." n, ".TBL_CATEGORIES." p 
       WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft 
       AND p.rgt 
       AND n.cat_ID='".$row['post_category']."' 
       ORDER BY p.lft";

    $result2=mysql_query($sql2);

    while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $path.='/'.$row2['cat_nicename'];
    }

    $link.='<a href="'.$path.'">'.$row['post_title'].'</a><br>';
    $path='';

}
echo($link);
exit;

}
```

This is how I get path in the link.. now What i want is:

I want to combine both queries so, that I do not have run the second query in while loop .. 
It gets very bad because if I receive 100 posts.. second query will run 100 times to fetch the path.

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` the two tables like so:

```
SELECT 
  p.ID, 
  p.post_title,  
  c.cat_nicename, 
  p.post_perma 
FROM       TBL_POSTS p
INNER JOIN TBL_CATEGORIES c 
        ON p.CategoryID = c.Cat_ID
WHERE      p.published = '1' 
  AND      p.page = '0' 
ORDER BY   p.ID ASC 
 LIMIT 50
```

Comment: If you want to show only the links, exactly as in your example, use inner join. Otherwise, if you need to also show some results of the first query, even if the second one returns nothing, use left outer join.

Comment: Did you notice thAT "Links" are being made in second nested while loop? that is not just one query.. in second while loop it gets child parent relationship in an array and then it makes path.. in your query i will only get one "Last" category_nicename .. did you get buddy i am trying to explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION to combine all of them into a single query.

Really, you would need to do something like this so that all of the columns don't get combined into each other. Also, both select statements need to have the same number of columns being selected.

EDIT: Also, in MySQL UNION's you can only have 1 order by and it has to be in the last SELECT, so you will have to adjust your query accordingly.

```
 (SELECT    ID, 
    post_title, 
    post_category, 
    post_perma, 
    NULL AS cat_id,
    NULL AS cat_nicename
  FROM ".TBL_POSTS."
  WHERE   published='1' 
  AND   page='0')
  ORDER BY  ID ASC LIMIT 50
UNION
(SELECT 
     NULL AS ID, 
     NULL AS post_title, 
     NULL AS post_category, 
     NULL AS post_perma, 
     p.cat_ID, 
     p.cat_nicename 
FROM ".TBL_CATEGORIES." n, 
     ".TBL_CATEGORIES." p
WHERE n.cat_ID='".post_category."' 
AND n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt)
ORDER BY p.lft
```

Comment: No. it didn't work before to.. says "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Comment: Even if i try your query as it is .. it says  "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' post_title, post_category, post_perma, NULL,NULL FROM tbl_posts WHERE ' at line 1

Comment: I missed the alias 'p', just added it. And there was a random AS after ID. Sorry about that.

Comment: "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"  Same error again :(  I am not familiar with union otherwise i would have solved it by myself :(

Comment: Check this page out, i'm sure it will help you. I wish I had a better answer, but I can't see what you're looking at. But this is most likely what you need. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Comment: Also, I've never had to use use this in MySQL, only Oracle and SQL Server, so the syntax may be slightly different in certain cases.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18300/discussion-between-user1713941-and-jcalabris)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MySql [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) or [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)